# OpenAPI optional object default value

Tags: openapi

Suppose you have the following OpenAPI requestBody specification:

```yaml
requestBody:
  required: true
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          field1:
            type: number
            default: 1
          field2:
            type: object
            properties:
              subfield:
                type: number
                default: 2
```

The request body contains:

- a `number` field with default value 1
- an `object` field, containing itself a `number` field with default value 2

If a client sends an empty payload, we should agree that `field1` value is supposed to be `1`, but what about `field2` value?

1. `field2` is not specified, so it must be considered as null
2. `field2` should be an object build with default values: `{subfield: 2}`
3. OpenAPI does not answer this question and that's up to me to decide what my application should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct behaviour would be your alternative `1`, with a twist.

`field2` should be considered to be "not present" and not `null` as there is some difference between those cases, see https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1775 for some discussion related to that difference.

From a validation point-of-view `field2` is not declared as `nullable` an object like `{"field2": null}` should not be valid, but `{}` would be.

Whether "not present" or `null` should be handled differently is up to your application.